# Insert trigger in postgresql, dynamic statement

Tags: postgresql, stored-procedures

I am trying to add an insert trigger to a table in order to implement partitioning.
The following code works:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION item_lines_insert_trigger()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO item_lines_partitions.p11_1 VALUES (NEW.*);
    RETURN NULL;
END;
$$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

My problem - is that when I try to make it dynamic (so that I can redirect to a table based on the values that I get), I just can't insert the record (NEW.*) into a dynamic statement.
Here is what I Tried to do:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION item_lines_insert_trigger()
RETURNS TRIGGER AS $$
BEGIN
    EXECUTE format('INSERT INTO item_lines_partitions.p%s_%s VALUES ',NEW.tenant_id,NEW.store_id) || quote_literal(NEW.*);
    RETURN NULL;
END;
```

I get a syntax error as following with the dynamic statement:
`PG::SyntaxError: ERROR:  syntax error at or near "'(49563,,1,11,100125,100125,1,,...`

I also tried using `EXECUTE <expression ... $1> USING NEW.*` but it did not work as well.

Any ideas on how to insert NEW.* expression into a dynamic statement?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
EXECUTE
   format(
      'INSERT INTO item_lines_partitions.%I SELECT ($1::text::item_lines_partitions.%I).*',
      'p' || NEW.tenant_id || '_' || NEW.store_id,
      'p' || NEW.tenant_id || '_' || NEW.store_id
   )
   USING NEW;
```

Here, `NEW` is used as a parameter to the statement and type cast to the appropriate table type.

The way you construct the table string was not safe, so I changed that.

Comment: Thanks. It did not work.
I got the following error:
```PG::CannotCoerce: ERROR:  cannot cast type item_lines to item_lines_partitions.p11_1```
where item_lines is the parent table name (I do partitioning with table inheritance)

Comment: Now I get the following:
```ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::DatatypeMismatch: ERROR:  column "id" is of type integer but expression is of type item_lines_partitions.p11_1)```
I Assume this is because I have many column types in that table.
Thank you very much for your help.
I can provide the table schema if that helps, but in general I have datatypes of text, integer, float, date, and time